# Back button handler not being registered when opening the app via push notification

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification

I have an app written in Ionic v1 and AngularJS.
The app is using `$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction` to handle the device's back button action.
Everything is working great when normally using the app. The problem is starting when the app is being opened by a push notification.

When the app is not in the background, and is being opened by clicking the push notification, the back button handler is not being registered and the physical back button throws me out of the app.
If I click anywhere on the screen (click, not scroll) then the touch event is being registered and everything is working well.

I have tried registering the event in multiple locations after the push notification event is launched.
I have tried simulating a touch event programaticlly on an empty space on the screen.
I have tried dispatching the resume event to simulate a return from paused state.
I have tried reloading the page programmaticlly after page loads.
Nothing seems to work.

The is my `$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction` event handler that is being registered in app.run:

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            function showConfirm() {
                var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
                    title : 'Close',
                    template : '<div>Do you want to close the app?</div>',
                    buttons : [
                        {
                            text : '<b>Cancel</b>'
                        }, 
                        {
                            text : '<b>Approve</b>',
                            type: 'button-positive',
                            onTap : function() {
                                ionic.Platform.exitApp();
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });
            };

            // Is there a page to go back to?
            if ($ionicHistory.backView()) {
                // Go back in history
                if($rootScope.pushPressed2) {
                    $location.path('/app/home').replace();
                }
                else {
                    $rootScope.backButtonPressed = true;
                    $ionicHistory.backView().go();
                }
            } 
            else {
                if($rootScope.pushPressed2) {
                    $location.path('/app/home').replace();
                }
                else {
                    showConfirm();
                }
            }

            return false;
        }, 101);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function(event) 
    {
       if ($ionicHistory.currentStateName() === "home"   ) 
    { 

           $cordovaDialogs.confirm('Are You Sure You Want to Exit?', 'AppName', ['Cancel','OK'])
        .then(function(buttonIndex) {
          // no button = 0 'OK' = 1 'Cancel' = 2
          var btnIndex = buttonIndex;
          if(buttonIndex==2)
          {
              ionic.Platform.exitApp();
          }
        });
        } 
else
        {
            if($ionicHistory.currentStateName() === "login" )
            {
                ionic.Platform.exitApp();
            }
            else
            {
                $ionicHistory.goBack();
            }

        }


      }, 100);
```

Comment: This is not an answer to my question.